# College Scorecard data dictionary missing academic.program_available.XXX entries

Tags: api, collegescorecard

I'm looking at the College Scorecard raw data zip downloaded from https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/ ("All Data") and the included `data_dictionary.yaml` that defines the data fields and their source in the included .csv files.

My issue, if I understand correctly, is due to the included `data_dictionary.yaml` missing entries for:

- `academic.program_available.assoc`
- `academic.program_available.bachelors`
- `academic.program_available.assoc_or_bachelors`

These are the fields that allow the search to query on schools that offer different degree types, either 2-year, 4-year, or both. Without these entries in the yaml, I don't know what they should link up to in the source csv columns and I'm not sure how the college scorecard site is able to query on these variables if they are not defined in the yaml (or in the csv?).

Perhaps the download doesn't contain the most recent `dictionary_data.yaml` file that the https://collegescorecard.ed.gov site is using? The file version is: `Aug27-2015-09-04-15:41-0700-allyears`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest data dictionary is available in JSON format here:

https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/data.json?api_key=YOURKEYHERE

Comment: Many of these variables can potentially change value by academic year. It's likely that these program_available variables need to be preceded by the year. E.g., 2014.academic.program_available.assoc. I am basing my comment on looking through the data and data dictionary for the recently updated Scorecard database (mid-Sept 2016).